# what the best NoSQL solution for windows server?

Tags: nosql

what the best NoSQL solution for windows server? preferably open source

Comment: define 'best'. Ie, what are the criteria that matter most to *you*

Comment: No, seriously, define "best". NoSQL is such a huge category. It does not really say what you want to do. Do you want a flat/document DB? An object DB? A directed graph DB? It depends on what you need to do. After that decision is made then you can choose "good candidates" based on your functional requirements.

Comment: for serving a wiki like website

Answer (score 5):

You should consider using [Redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/). It's an advanced NoSQL database with support for rich server-side data structures such as lists, sets, sorted sets and hashes. It is also one of the fastest NoSQL databases around: 110000 SETs/second, 81000 GETs/second in an entry level Linux box. [Check the benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/Benchmarks).

I have a feature-rich open source C# client that let's you persist any C# POCO type natively available at:
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

Here are some benchmarks comparing the [Redis C# client vs RavenDB](http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=474).

The client provides a rich interface providing wrappers for .NET's generic IList, IDictionary and ICollection for Redis's rich server side data structures.

If you want to view a good tutorial on how you can use it to develop a real-world application check out:
http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/DesigningNoSqlDatabase

Here's an example from the page above showing how easy it is to store and retrieve C# objects:

```
var redis = new RedisClient();
using (var redisUsers = redisClient.GetTypedClient<User>())
{
    redisUsers.Store(new User { Id = redisUsers.GetNextSequence(), Name = "demis" });
    redisUsers.Store(new User { Id = redisUsers.GetNextSequence(), Name = "mythz" });

    var allUsers = redisUsers.GetAll();

    Console.WriteLine(allUsers.Dump());
}
/*Output
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Name: ayende,
        BlogIds: []
    },
    {
        Id: 2,
        Name: mythz,
        BlogIds: []
    }
]
 */
```

Although the server is primarily developed on Linux I have windows redis-server builds available at:
http://code.google.com/p/servicestack/wiki/RedisWindowsDownload

Comment: One thing to note: Redis is an in-memory database. It's not designed for big data.

Answer (score 3):

[RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) by [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/) is the only one written in .net (that I know of), so it "just works" on Windows.

It is Open Source, but it has a dual license:
you can use it for free if your project is Open Source as well, otherwise you have to purchase a [commercial license](http://ravendb.net/licensing).

Answer (score 2):

I have used [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org) on Windows and the install went pretty smoothly.  I haven't put a real heavy load on it yet.

And you can find a [.NET driver here](http://github.com/robconery/NoRM) for Mongo if that's your platform

Answer (score 1):

A bit old answer but there's an approach giving you a nosql'ish document store behavior over SQL-server, http://www.sisodb.com

Answer (score 1):

You could [NosDB](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/) a try. Its a NoSQL database written completely in .NET which supports [SQL queries](http://www.alachisoft.com/nosdb/sql-cheat-sheet.html) as well.

It's [open source with Apache 2.0 License](https://github.com/Alachisoft/NosDB) so its completely free without any strings attached.

The answer to whether is it the best or not is completely opinion based so you should check it out yourself.